# How to hide datagrid container using DataTrigger if it has no items 

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a datagrid that binds its data from SelectedItem of a TreeView.

The problem is how to **auto hide** the grid container using **DataTrigger** if the **datagrid has no items**   ?

```
    <Grid Name="grid1" Visibility="Visible">
       <DataGrid Name="datagrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=treeview1, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
    </Grid>
```

I think this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ce51b1b7-dd83-4279-a6a9-656c2aa3924e) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the data source in the code behind, during a page load event. If the data source is empty (according to your criteria), then set datagrid1.visible = false. For completeness sake, set it to true if you do find some data worth displaying.

Answer (score 8):

This data trigger worked for me:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could bind to the HasItems property of the datagrid. But since that property is a boolean type and the Grid.Visibility is a Visibility enum, you'd need to convert the boolean to enum.  Luckily, there already is an out-of-the-box converter called BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

```
<Grid Name="grid1" Visibility="{Binding HasItems, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, ElementName=datagrid1, Mode=OneWay}">
```

Not sure why you want to use a DataTrigger, but if you want to apply transitions when changing visibility, you could do so by styling the grid and adding a trigger for when Visibility=Visible, like so:

```
<Style x:Key="GridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="StoryboardShow">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="{x:Null}">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard x:Key="StoryboardHide">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="{x:Null}">
                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryboardHide}"/>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource StoryboardShow}"/>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Then apply this style to the grid:

```
<Grid Name="grid1" Style="{DynamicResource GridStyle1}" Visibility="{Binding HasItems, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, ElementName=datagrid1, Mode=OneWay}">
```

Comment: Any idea about using DataTrigger for this problem?

Comment: I want something like [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ce51b1b7-dd83-4279-a6a9-656c2aa3924e)

Comment: Great solution! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">    
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="2"
            CornerRadius="1"
            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                        <Grid>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ScroItemsPresenter" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Block" Text="asd"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Block" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="ScroItemsPresenter" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

HasItems:
[image]
noItems:
[image]